# TypeError: tensor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'

Tags: python, pytorch

so I started  reading deep learning with pytorch, and got to the point of setting names to the dimensions inside the tensor, to make it more friendly, but as soon as I use the names argument, I get the error:

```
TypeError: tensor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'
```

can anyone help me out?

The code is simple:

```
import torch

weights_named = torch.tensor([0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722], names=['channels'])
weights_named
```

Just want to run this, to see how to set names to the dimensions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your PyTorch version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your PyTorch Version. Upgrade your Pytorch version and should work. In my case,

```
import torch
torch.__version__ #1.7
weights_named = torch.tensor([0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722], names=['channels'])
# __main__:1: UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change.
```

[Named tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/named_tensor.html) and functions supporting it on latest 1.9 release, but on 1.7 (my version) is still experimental.

Comment: Hi dmatos2012, I have pytorch version 1.2, i cant seem to be able to update it for names to work. I'm using jupyter notebook. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think depends on what environment you are using, but I think  a simple
`!pip install torch==1.7.1` or something should be enough to update it.